# jQuery can't get toggle to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having one of those days where I just can't think straight.

Basically have a div off screen, on a click in slides in from the left (got that working fine), I need it to slide out when clicked again.

**CSS**

tablet flyout is absolute positioned within rotator so I can't use display: none to hide the rotator overlay and toggle through.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rotator-overlay">
 <div class="tablet-flyout">+</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $('.tablet-flyout').click(function () {
          $('.rotator-overlay').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
     })
```

I've used `slideToggle` before but only had success when toggling through display block/display none.

Comment: There is a slideToggle() method you can use instead of animate and toggle seperately: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: I mentioned that i used slidetoggle but it didnt work

Comment: slideToggle() won't work here since he is moving the element left/right, not show/hiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the div state in a variable and then check it inside the click function. So if the div is off screen, slide it in, if not, slide it out.

If you don't want to use a variable for that, you can always check for `$('.rotator-overlay').css('left')` and do the appropriate action based on the value you get.

Something like this (I took -200 as an example):

```
$('.travel-search-tablet-flyout').click(function () {
    if ($('.rotator-overlay').css('left') == 0)
        $('.rotator-overlay').animate({ left: '-200' }, 500);
    else
        $('.rotator-overlay').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the left of the element you are trying to slide, and use an if statement to toggle back and forth.

```
 $('.travel-search-tablet-flyout').click(function () {
   if ($('.rotator-overlay').css('left') == 0) {
     // Slide the other way here, opposite
     // $('.rotator-overlay').animate({ left: '????' }, 500);
   } else {
     // Your original animate
     $('.rotator-overlay').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
   }
 })
```